# Tutte polynomial of $K_4$ graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to find the Tutte polynomial of a K4 graph. I tried to first find the subgraph of K4, which has 6 graphs with 1 edge, 12 graphs with 2 edges, 8 graphs with 3 edges, and when $A = ∅$ and $A = E(K_4)$.

Can anyone give me some help on how to start with this? I just need a little help on how to start with that...

And after this question, can anyone give me some hints on how to find the Tutte polynomial of $K_4 − e$??

I have been trying for the whole night but I'm still get stuck on how to obtain the polynomial for the $K_4$ graph

Thanks a lot

Comment: The Tutte polynomial is defined recursively, and you can use this definition itself to compute the polynomial.